# Disable latest posts from being queried in the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I was tasked to display posts group by their categories, and I suppose I could do that with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). The problem is, [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) still queries for the latests posts on the index page. How do I prevent that from happening?

I used the plugin [MySQL Profiler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mysql-profiler) to check what were being queried.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use custom query in index.php.

Something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC' 
    );

    $temp=$wp_query;//save the main query

    $wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      get_template_part(...);
    endwhile;

   $wp_query=$temp;//restore the main $wp_query
```

And to group posts by categories I would use [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37362/28218) from WordPress StackExchange.